# Devise rails 4 signup insert empty profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, registration

I'm using rails 4 with Devise 3.2.4. In my app I'm trying to have a signup page with profile attributes. In my mind I got it, but if I call the page the registration controller inserts a empty dataset.

My Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile: [:vorname, :nachname]) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :login

  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy , autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 5.minutes


  validates :username, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, message: "may only contain letters and numbers." }


  before_create :build_profile



  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
end
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Registration/new.html.erb

```
<div class="authform">
  <% @user.build_profile if @user.profile.nil? %>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Sign up</h3>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :username %>
      <%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_fields| %>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= profile_fields.label :vorname %>
        <%= profile_fields.text_field :vorname, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= profile_fields.label :nachname %>
        <%= profile_fields.text_field :nachname, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
     <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What is my mistake?

logfile:

```
    Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-13 17:46:49 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-05-13 15:46:49.658114"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-13 15:46:49.658114"]]
  [1m[36m (2.3ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (22.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 45.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)


Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-13 17:49:23 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pfVuUhs7+CnYOnKhK35nrsb/07e/T6VxPD2meCg4fEw=", "user"=>{"username"=>"Furkan", "email"=>"Furkan_adiguezel@hotmail.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile_attributes"=>{"vorname"=>"Furkan", "nachname"=>"Adigüzel", "id"=>"43"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: id
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 79ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:398:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:343:in `profile_attributes='
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:56:in `block in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:56:in `assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:36:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:452:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:20:in `new_with_session'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:95:in `build_resource'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
   () Users/furkanadiguzel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
   () Users/furkanadiguzel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
   () Users/furkanadiguzel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/2171916440/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-13 17:49:23 +0200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have specified `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` in `User` model, you would receive the `profile` attributes in `params` hash with key `profile_attributes` (**singular** profile as 1-1 Relationship).

With this in mind, you must whitelist the profile specific attributes under key `profile_attributes` BUT currently you have whitelisted key `profile` which is why registration controller is inserting an empty dataset for `profile` record.

Update the `configure_permitted_parameters` method in `ApplicationController` as below:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  ## Changed "profile" to "profile_attributes" and permitted `:id`
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:vorname, :nachname, :id]) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

**NOTE:**

`before_create` callback is not required in `User` model. You are creating an extra `Profile` there. So, **remove it.**

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem. My assume is that in my user model something went wrong.

Comment: It should work. Did you get any error after implementing my answer? Are you still getting empty datasets for Profile?

Comment: I've got the same problem this are my logs                                                                               Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-13 17:11:26 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-05-13 15:11:26.995238"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-13 15:11:26.995238"]]
   (6.3ms)  commit transaction

Comment: Can you please add the complete logs(including the params hash, as I don't see it in the current logs) in the question so that they are more readable and visible to everyone.

Comment: Share the complete server logs generated upon registration form submission.

Comment: @user3608170 Read the updated answer. I have modified `configure_permitted_parameters` method and also added a NOTE in the end.

Comment: Thank you two. Your answer worked fine with an addition. I changed the build_profile to create_profile and it works fine.